# How Do I Send CallKit API Request When App Is In Background?

Tags: ios, voip, callkit

I am working with the `VoIP CallKit`. When the app is in the background, I get a notification and `CallKit UI` is shown to the user.

If the call is rejected, then `CallKit` is dismissed - but I have to send an API request to the server. However, it's not going as the app is in the background. How should I send the API request?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use a background task and start it before the call to `action.fullfill()` as follows:

```
func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXEndCallAction)
{
    // Start a background task that calls the server API

    action.fulfill()
}
```

You can use [this API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/extending_your_app_s_background_execution_time) to implement the background task.